# how to check if condition more than once in Shell Script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am creating a shell script which checks the status of a service running on another machine and if didn't get any response than performs some operation at the local system. I am using if clause in the script for this task.

Sometimes due to the network connection, it falsely assumes that the remote server is not responding and performs the tasks mentioned inside if clause. I want to set up a retry so that it checks if condition more than once when it didn't find any response in the first attempt.

is there any way to setup retry like thing in a shell script for this purpose?

Below is a sample code

```
RSI1_STATUS=$(psql -U username -h serverip -d postgres -t -c "select version();" )


if [ -z "$RSI1_STATUS" ]  #Condition will be true if remote server is not active
then    
   touch /tmp/postgresql.trigger       
fi
```

now I want to check if condition more than once if it is true in the first attempt.

Comment: Yes, use `for` or `while` loops. `help for`, `help while`

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add retry loop with a number of retries using a `while` loop:

```
retries=5
while ! check_network_connection && ((--retries)); do
    sleep 1 # or probe the network, etc.
done

if [[ $retries -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Error: Connection retries exhausted."
else
   # connection succeeded.
fi
```

Whether you want to sleep or do something else depends on your usage and the application.

Note: The "network connection" might have succeeded *after* checking in the loop. So if `retries` is 0, it doesn't necessarily mean that the connection is still down.